# web application not work via internal domain

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, dns, appdomain

I did search online and found some similar posts but didn't resolve mine.

Here is my issue:

1. It's a asp.net web application running on IIS7
2. It has an internal domain name like xxx/yyy(xxx stands for the server name, and yyy is the application name on IIS), a full domain name like xxx.company.com/yyy(visible from external internet) and ip address like 192.168.000.000/yyy

Right now it could be visited properly from its full domain(xxx.company.com/yyy) and from its ip address, but not be visited properly from its internal domain name(xxx/yyy).  More ridiculous, only some computers have the issue but some not, they are all using ie11...

Then in command window, I could ping its internal domain address, with correct ip reply.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What error do you get? What doesn't work using the internal name?

Comment: first the entire web frame got squeezed into a small size and had error popup saying "Invalid argument"

Comment: By default, IE displays intranet web sites in "compatibility view" mode. Can you check that and try disabling it?

Comment: Check your searchlist for "company.com"...computers don't actually understand "xxx" as a resolvable address. If the FQDN and IP address work, but "xxx/yyy" doesn't, I can just about guarantee that your problem is name resolution or an internal proxy.